# Spring 4 get init parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have some init parameters declared in web.xml that must be defined for my spring application to function. Inside of my controller, I have:

```
@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext){
    this.servletContext = servletContext;
    validateServletInitParameters();
}
```

Inside `validateServletInitParameters()` I want to check to make sure all the values are present, and if not, throw the equivalent of a servlet exception. How can I do this in Spring (4)? The setServletContextMethod does not throw any exceptions, so I'm not sure what to do.

The init parameters are declared in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <description>Represents the maximum input amount</description>
    <param-name>maximumInputAmount</param-name>
    <param-value>500.00</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: why not throw a runtime exception?

Comment: I agree with John... throw a runtime exception (like IllegalStateException o InvalidArgumentException)

Comment: Don't... If you use `@Value` to inject the values into your bean you will automatically get an error stating that properties cannot be resolved. Or if you really want to do it manually you can inject the `Environment` and do `getRequiredProperty` which will result in an error then.